# Apache2 sometimes serving old SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, apache2

We renewed the wildcard ssl certificate on our Apache2 webserver on ubuntu 16.04. Most of the time, the website serves this new certificate and everything is fine. However, sometimes it serves the previous expired certificate. This can be resolved by just refreshing the page. This is the only site being hosted on this server.

How could this be happening and what can be done to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that multiple instances of Apache2 were running for some unknown reason. To fix:

```
sudo killall apache2
sudo service apache2 start
```